# Android text input layout change selected status color

Tags: android

In TextInputLayout when use it as a dropdown list I wanna remove the ripple color  that happen on click

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DsWoM.png)
TextInput hint

Comment: can't understand your question .

Comment: In TextInputLayout when use it as a dropdown list I wanna remove the ripple color that happen on click @DrHowdyDoo

Answer (score 0):

Try setting the background to transparent

```
android:background="@android:color/transparent"
```